# How to get value of child node from XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I need to get value of child node from XDocument using linq

```
<root>
<Cust>
     <ACTNumber>1234</ACTNumber>
     <Address>
         <Street></Street>
         <City>123 Main street</City>
         <State>AL</State>
     </Address>
</Cust>
</root>
```

I tried this: `xDocTest.Root.Elements("Cust").Elements("ACTNumber")`

If I try Address instead of ACTNumber then it works. But its not giving the child node value.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If there's only one `Cust` element and only one `ACTNumber` element, then it's easy:

```
string actNumber = doc.Root.Element("Cust").Element("ACTNumber").Value;
```

Or to get it as a `long`:

```
long actNumber = (long) doc.Root.Element("Cust").Element("ACTNumber");
```

Comment: is it really necessary to put `doc.Root.Element().Element()`? What is the shortest way to get to "ACTNumber" straight away, first occurence, no matter what level it is found in?

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester: For that, you'd use `doc.Descendants("ACTNumber").First()`

Answer (score 8):

Use this:

```
xDocTest.Root.Element("Cust").Element("Adress").Element("City").Value
```

If you use Elements (note the plural) it gives u an IEnumerable, this would be used like this:

XML

```
<Father>
    <Child>Hello</Child>
    <Child>World!</Child>
</Father>
```

C#

```
foreach(var childElement in Root.Elements("Child")) Console.WriteLine(childElement.Value);
```

Or to take your example:

```
foreach(var child in xdoc.Root.Element("Cust").Element("Address").Elements()) 
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} : {1}", child.Name, child.Value);
```

Im not sure how Element behaves if you have multiple Elements of the same name. So you might want to use Elements and Inerate over all occurences.

And in Linq
If there is more than one Customer...

```
var result = from cust in xdoc.Root.Elements("Cust")

             where cust.Elements("ACTNumber").Any() // This is to make sure there
                                                    // is an element called ACTNumber
                                                    // otherwise .Value would create
                                                    // Nullrefexception.

             select child.Element("ACTNumber").Value;
```

Comment: You can't, that's the primary point of a code block, to prevent any markup from being treated as markup instead of text.

Comment: I wanted to use it in my sentence starting with "If you use..."

Comment: I want to get ACTNumber value and prefer linq expression so that I won't need to write for loop for each element

Comment: That shouldnt be so hard to turn a foreach into a from...select

Comment: @user1532976: Will there definitely only be one ACTNumber?

Comment: I took my example back and set it to one ACTNumber per customer.
If that isnt enought examplecode to understand how things work, there might be some way different problem here...

Comment: @Jon Skeet Yes there will be only one ACTNumber.