# How to read simple XML?

Tags: c#, .net, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML string but can't figure out a way to get the values out of an XDocument.

```
<root>
  <Address>1st Street</Address>
  <City>Denver<City>
</root>
```

I'm using:

```
XDocument mydoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
```

From there, I can't get access "FirstName" and get the value.  Any one know how to do this?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of this question?  FYI I don't see "FirstName" in the XML you've pasted.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221558/how-to-get-value-of-child-node-from-xdocument

Comment: Is your xml missing "FirstName" or do you mean `FirstAttribute` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without XPath

```
var xAddress = mydoc.Root.Element("Address");
var xCity = mydoc.Root.Element("City");

var address = xAddress != null ? xAddress.Value : null;
var city = xCity != null ? xCity.Value : null;
```

You can also use Linq on it:

```
var fordTrucks = someXml.Root.Elements.Where(elem.Attributes("Type").Value == "Ford");
```

Or you can transform that into an actual class:

```
var fordTrucks = someXml.Root.Elements.Where(elem => elem.Attributes("Type").Value == "Ford").Select(elem => {
    return new Truck() {
        Type = Enum.Parse(TypeOf(TruckTypes), elem.Attribute("Type").Value),
        Model = elem.Attribute("Model").Value
    }
});
```

Comment: If Address and City are guaranteed to be in the xml file, then you don't need to check if they are null.  However I always do, so that I can always allow for them to not be in the XML file.

Comment: you can also do `var address = (string)mydoc.Root.Element("Address");`.  The implementation of the explicit conversion to string in LINQ to XML will return null if the element (or attribute) is not found.  Less code to write that way :)